# C# XmlSerializer - There is an error in XML document 0,0) <nodename> not expected

Tags: c#, xml

I posted a different flavour of this problem before with no joy.  I'm hoping a refactored question will help.

Essentially, i'm loading an XML string into an XDocument then using XDocument.GetReader() to return a XmlReader.  From here I'm using a XmlSerializer to deserialise the following XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osgb:FeatureCollection
xmlns:osgb='http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb'
xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml'
xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/schema/v7/OSDNFFeatures.xsd'
fid='GDS-58116-1'>
  <gml:description>OS</gml:description>
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
  </gml:boundedBy>
  <osgb:queryTime>2009-07-30T02:35:17</osgb:queryTime>
  <osgb:queryExtent>
    <osgb:Rectangle srsName='osgb:BNG'>
      <gml:coordinates>291000.000,92000.000 293000.000,94000.000</gml:coordinates>
    </osgb:Rectangle>
  </osgb:queryExtent>  
</osgb:FeatureCollection>
```

to this class (generated using XSD)

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("FeatureCollection", Namespace = "http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class FeatureCollectionType : AbstractFeatureCollectionType
{

    private System.DateTime queryTimeField;

    private GeometryPropertyType queryExtentField;

    private System.DateTime queryChangeSinceDateField;

    private bool queryChangeSinceDateFieldSpecified;

    private FeatureAssociationType[] _featureMemberField;

    private BoundingShapeType boundedBy1Field;

    //  more properties

}
```

The inner exception shows that: `<FeatureCollection xmlns='http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb'> was not expected`.

I can't see what the problem it.  I don't need a root node above the collection do I?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx) method? There is no need to do these two previous steps.

Comment: coming from a URI, using WebClient to get the XML

Comment: same problem using `XmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream)` method, i'm obviously missing something but cannot see what

Comment: Can you add the actual deserialization code (`XmlSerialization` instantiation and stuff)? Because there is probably an issue with that.

Comment: In a small testproject, create a FeatureCollectionType instance and serialize it to file. Compare the XMLs.

Comment: thanks henk, found the problem though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested a simplified version (with all properties removed from `FeatureCollectionType`), and it didn't throw at the first element:

```
private static string xml = 
@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osgb:FeatureCollection
   xmlns:osgb='http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb'
   xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml'
   xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
   xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
   xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/schema/v7/OSDNFFeatures.xsd'
   fid='GDS-58116-1'>
</osgb:FeatureCollection>";

public static void RunSnippet()
{
    using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FeatureCollectionType));
        var obj = xs.Deserialize(sr);
        Console.WriteLine("if you are reading this, it didn't throw");
    }
}
```

How are you instantiating `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: thanks guys! cheers for sanity check groo.  was doing similar thing, stripping it back, in the meantime.  turns out I had another version of the xsd generated class in the same namespace. because xsd.exe makes partial classes, it wasn't being thrown up by ide.  Hope this helps someone else making a silly mistake.  thanks for your time (and sorry for wasting it!)